# Alter the HTML of an asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010

I am still very much a beginner when it comes to programming. I have Visual Studio 2010 and I am writing in C#. I am trying to use the asp:menu control and I am wondering for both this control and pretty much any other... how would I edit the output html of the control.

Example:

asp:menu rendered

```
<div>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to edit it so it would include a span tag around the a href tag.

```
<li><span><a href="#"></a></span></li>
```

How would I go about doing this? Or can you point to be some ref information that could better assist me. Thank you ahead of time for any help you can give.

Comment: Do you mean <li><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>?

Comment: Hi Th3Ph1l0s0ph3r, Welcome to Programmers!  This is a Q/A site for getting expert answers on **conceptual** problems relating to software development.  Specific issues like this should be posted to StackOverflow in the future.  Please see the FAQ for more information.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

There are the (outdated?) [ASP.NET 2.0 CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/) which also "rewrite" the code of the rendered controls.

If you take a look on how they do it, it should rather easy for you to insert your own code for the menu.

On the other hand, I see no real need for inserting a `<span>` tag, since you still should be able to apply CSS to the `<a>` tag without the extra span tag.

Comment: Asp.net 2.0 CSS Friendly Cotrol Adapters have been outdated since VS 2010. I already have my menus in the same list item mode as those controls would have done. I am simply want to know if there is an easy way to edit the design/layout of a control to better suit my needs.